# select data from multi column level

Tags: pandas

I have DataFrame called stocks
 with index being dates, first level column being "High","Low", "Close", second level being stock tickers, looks like below:
[image]

I want select all Close prices by 
stocks_close = stocks['Close']

however it gives an error as:
KeyError: Close

I dont understand as how should select, I think it is making sense to do stocks['Close'] without specifying column index level, can anyone help me to explain how and why?

Thanks !

Comment: Since `Close` is in the first level, it should work. You may want to check if your column names has trailing white spaces, e.g. `'Close '`. For example, you can do `print(stocks.columns)`.

Comment: I looked, stocks.columns gives like this:Index([    ('Adj Close', 'Adj Close'), '('Adj Close', 'Adj Close').1',
       '('Adj Close', 'Adj Close').2', '('Adj Close', 'Adj Close').3',
       '('Adj Close', 'Adj Close').4', '('Adj Close', 'Adj Close').5',
                   ('Close', 'Close'),         '('Close', 'Close').1',
               '('Close', 'Close').2',         '('Close', 'Close').3',
               '('Close', 'Close').4',         '('Close', 'Close').5',
                    ...],
      dtype='object')

Comment: do not like what I expected .....I don't understand

Comment: That's not so good, `'('Close', 'Close').1'` and `dtype='object'` does not indicate a multi-index. You should see something like `MultiIndex([('High','IBM'), ('Close','IBM')...])` You should review your creation of dataframe.

Comment: This is not what I created, I used yfinance downloaded from yahoo finance directly, so it looks like this.....it looks like I need to do something before actually use data?

Comment: And I dont think that is the problem, as if I specify only one ticker name, there is no error